# log4net only works when XmlConfigurator.Configure() is called

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I understand that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445976/log4net-config-in-external-file-does-not-work/1479343#1479343) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519100/log4net-not-working) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618380/log4net-does-not-write-the-log-file) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481960/log4net-in-windows-forms-app-does-not-write-log-file) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850380/log4net-logging-problem-very-simple-file-appender-logging-not-working) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850380/log4net-logging-problem-very-simple-file-appender-logging-not-working) [times](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Log4net-NOT-working-on-net-4-5-td36572.html), but unfortunately, I haven't been able to get my logging configuration working.  I have to be making some very small mistake somewhere.

I have a .NET 4.5 MVC 4/EF 5 web application and I'm trying to get logging to work.  The solution has two projects, one for the DAO's and model objects, and one for the web site.
The App.Config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RebuildingTogetherEntities" connectionString="stuff..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <log4net configSource="Log.config" />
</configuration>
```

The same log4net section has also been copied into the Web.Config file.

I added the following to both AssemblyInfo.cs files:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log.config", Watch = true)]
```

"Copy To Output Directory" is set to true for both Log.Config files.

The only way that I can seem to get logging to append to the output file is to call XmlConfigurator.Configure() before the first logging statement runs.  I guess I can write a facade to do that when I first obtain the logger, but that just feels wrong.

How can I initialize the logger without calling the XmlConfigurator manually?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971250/log4net-configuration-from-assembly-attribute-does-not-load-configuration-file apply?

Comment: It would appear not... in that case, there was a message from log4net before application shutdown, but I don't see that message in my case.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Not sure I agree with your logic. You won't see the log4net message unless internal logging is on, and if your system isn't reading your log.config then it probably won't be on. The important point is that when you do something like GetLogger(...) the system will basically do something equivalent to Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(),  typeof(log4net.Config.ConfiguratorAttribute), false) . Hence if you don't log very early in your application startup, then your first logger may be initialized from an assembly that does not continue the custom attribute.

Comment: I LOVE how logging frameworks FAIL SILENTLY

Answer (score 35):

I have faced exactly the same issue. As you rightly point out, you should not need to explicitly call `XmlConfigurator` when you include the line in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`. The problem comes when the first use of log4net is in an assembly that doesn't have that line. In my case I was using the [`Topshelf.Log4Net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf.Log4Net) NuGet package, and the first log line that my application logged was through that.

You could just log a line early in your app or if you don't need to log anything do what I did and add the following at the entry point of the application

```
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
```

Comment: Great answer. We had the same problem where an object that was being auto created by our DI container was spitting out a line of logging before the main application.

Comment: What a life saver. Put it in global.asax.cs and it worked perfectly. Spent literally a day for this.

Comment: What is Program in this case?

Comment: A `Program` class is commonly used as the entry point for C# apps. You could use any class from your entry assembly though.

Comment: After many google searches, and stackoverflow wrong answers, why hasn't this been marked as the correct answer?

Comment: I am not sure from where LogManager is? I got red highlight.

Comment: @HninHtetHtetAung it is used to instantiate loggers in log4net. Have you checked [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)?

Comment: @ChrisGessler this is not a workaround, it is [as specified in the attribute documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes) - _"…  it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked."_

Comment: Hurrah! Been banging my head on the table with this one. Thx :)

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to call the XmlConfigurator manually if you use:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log.config", Watch = true)]
```

However you have to **add the tag to all your dlls** (all assambly.cs files).

Comment: The application still does not log even if this is added, unfortunately.

Comment: You can enable log4net debugging: http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: Could you please explain why do you recommned to add this attribute to *all* dll's instead of only the host one?

Comment: It will enable you to configure logging for each dll separately, different config files.

Comment: that [assembly] I suppose is in global.aspx, i use it on other projects and log4net going good, but i have one project doesnt work