# Log4net in a web service

Tags: asp.net, service, web, log4net

I basically have the same question as

[log4net only works when XmlConfigurator.Configure() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16766236/3169560)

However, I couldn't comment there as I don't have any reputation (just signed up).

Thanks for any helpful comments. 
If I do anything wrong here, please advise. 
Thank you very much. Bernd

Update: 
Thanks for constructive hints. I've have made some progress and therefore will explain in more detail: 
I use log4net within a (VS generated C# web service). I do get the debug information in the debug file, however within VS (2012) I do get the message for every logging call:

```
log4net:ERROR An exception ocurred while retreiving stack frame information.
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
     bei log4net.Core.StackFrameItem..ctor(StackFrame frame)
```

I configured it via XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>  
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/debug.log" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level (%class#%method:%line):%message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />    
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

My web service looks like this:

```
public class ObjectInfo : IObjectInfo
{    
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);



    public void DoWork()        {
      Logging.LoggingUtil.InitializeLogging();
      log.Debug("Some message");
    }
}
```

Hope this is quite sufficient. The LoggingUtil- class basically looks like this:

```
private const String Log4NetConfigurationFilePath = "log4net-config.xml"; //real path looks somewhat different
public static void InitializeLogging()
{    
  XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Log4NetConfigurationFilePath));     
}
```

I wonder, if the problem is that the stack trace cannot be found out within Cassine as Microsoft doesn't allow this in order to protect their implementation of the web service?

Comment: Show how you configure, initialize and call log4net.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I updated the post. Hope this is precise enough.

Comment: [What version are you using, and do you use dynamic methods](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-393)? Update to at least version 1.2.13, as they claim to have fixed that issue.

Comment: I'm using 1.2.12 and will try and update. I don't use dynamic methods. Actually, this is just plain Out-of-the-box VS web service. However, Microsoft might in the back ground. I will let you know about the update.

Comment: Updated to Version [1.2.13] or 2.0.3 respectively (I don't know why there are 2 version numbers for the same version). This fixed the issue.  @CodeCaster: Thank you very much. If you add your contribution as answer I'm happy to mark my question as solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [LOG4NET-393](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-393), this error occurs when there is a dynamic method in the call chain.

There they claim to have this error fixed in versions > `1.2.12`.

Comment: Sorry I can't vote this up as my reputation doesn't suffice. Maybe someone else will have a similar problem and get you some credit.