# Log4net appenders always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, log4net

I use log4net in my webapi project (using autofac and owin). I added this to my controller

```
LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NotificationController));
```

But I have seen that there is no appender loaded. In my config I have this

```
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
...    
<log4net>
        <root>
          <level value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
        </root>
        <appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
          </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />              
          </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
          <file value="log\server.log" />
          <appendToFile value="true" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />
          </layout>
        </appender>
      </log4net>
```

I have no build errors and my code is running without error if I call this

```
logger.Fatal("Error");
```

But I have no logs.

### UPDATE

Added this to startup class but doesn't change

```
public class Startup
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Startup));

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        logger.Info("Start application");
```

Answer (score 10):

Log4Net has to be told explicitly that you want it to read the XML configuration from App.config.

See: [log4net only works when XmlConfigurator.Configure() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766236/log4net-only-works-when-xmlconfigurator-configure-is-called)

Either call the static method `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in your application startup code, or add the following to `AssemblyInfo.cs` for all projects in the solution:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

You may also find that you have to call `LogManager.GetLogger()` immediately after startup - it seems to make a difference even if the logger instance is not used for anything.

Comment: You must call GetLogger on startup when using assembly attributes, as per [the docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes) - _"If you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked."**_